# Batch Resize in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize, batch-processing

I have about 600 images i need to resize. They are currently all different sizes and i need them to end up 2000x2000 pixels. I tried creating an action to resize them all, but i'm noticing they come out distorted. Images smaller than 2000px stretch to fit the page. Is there a way to keep the proportions of the image?

Comment: If your images have different proportions and you want them to be square... how do you want to keep the proportions?

Answer (score 0):

If these images don't already have a 1:1 (square) aspect ratio, then scaling to a 1:1 aspect ratio will distort the image. You may have to crop them to the desired aspect ratio first.

Cropping could be recorded as an action and run as a batch, but this would apply the same crop to every image, and that may not be what you want. You may have to crop them manually, depending on the image or location of the main subject.

If it's any help to you, I do this kind of thing often, but I don't use Photoshop to do it. I use Lightroom for manual cropping of multiple images. The benefit is that Lightroom is non-destructive, plus you don't need to save/export anything after making each crop. When you have finished you can export the images all in one go, and rescale at the same time.

It is also possible to rescale without distortion semi-automatically using [Content Aware scaling in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-scaling.html), however it's not guaranteed to work with every image. If the seam carving algorithm can't find sufficient spaces to add the seams, it will just mess up.